# Using MvcContrib.Pagination with MembershipUser.GetAllUsers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I cannot get the pager to work for my ListUsers page.  The method in my controller looks like:

```
public ActionResult ListUsers(int? page, int? pageSize) {   
    int totalItems;
    var members = Membership.GetAllUsers(page ?? 1, pageSize ?? 50, out totalItems);
    ViewData["Users"] = ToList<MembershipUser>(members);
    return View();
}
```

And my aspx page has the following looks like:

```
<% var users = ViewData["Users"] as List<MembershipUser>; %>

<% foreach( var user in users ){ %>
           Email is: <%= user.Email %>
<% } %>

<%= Html.Pager((IPagination)ViewData["Users"])%>
```

I get the error

"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Web.Security.MembershipUser]' to type 'MvcContrib.Pagination.IPagination'."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not using Html.Grid within my view.  I got it to work, but not sure if this is the best way code.  Here it is:

**(my controller)**

```
public ActionResult ListUsers(int? page, int? pageSize) {
```

int totalItems;
  var members = Membership.GetAllUsers(page ?? 0, pageSize ?? 50, out totalItems);
  ViewData["Users"] = ToList(members);
  // a second variable
  var members2 = Membership.GetAllUsers();
  ViewData["Users2"] = ToList(members2).AsPagination(page ?? 1, 50);
  return View();
}

**(my view)**

```
<%  var users = ViewData["Users"] as List; %>
```

<% foreach( var user in users ){ %>
   UserName: <%= user.UserName %>
   Email: <%= user.Email %>
<% } %>
//the pager
<%= Html.Pager("Users2")%>

Update: Paging is off by 1. Clicking "next" from the default page will skip a page. How do I fix this?  The .AsPagination() method does not accept 0 AND starting .GetAllUsers() at 1 will not show the actual first page.

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass a list to Html.Pager. You have to pass something that implements IPagination. You can build your own class, or you can create the LazyPagination class -- very easily through the .AsPagination() extension method.

See, e.g, http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/06/25/MvcContribGridPagerHelpers.aspx